# Policy Authorization in Azure Functions .net 6

Tags: c#, jwt, azure-functions, policy, .net-6.0

I'm attempting to migrate from a REST API that I developed in a Web App to Azure Functions.  In the Web App I use the "Authorize" attribute decoration with a Policy like:

```
[Authorize(Policy = Permissions.Announcements.Edit)]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyFunction([FromBody] MyDTO dto) 
{ 
/* my code */
}
```

The code uses JWT tokens for Authentication and ASP.NET Core Identity.
My question is there any way to accomplish Policies using Azure Functions v4 in .net 6? Maybe a custom middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **Azure Functions** don’t have any concept of middlewares, except for [**filters**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/do-you-know-azure-function-have-function-filters/) which are at the time of writing in [preview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters).

Azure Functions however support regular [**dependency injection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003178), so you can add your custom services. One of the services for example is `AddJwtBearer` brought to you by the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-5.0&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003178) package.

Instead of using plain JwtBearer middleware, we are going to use [**Microsoft.Identity.Web**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003178) (MIW).
The cool thing about MIW is that it simplifies most of the common actions and operations you need to do. It also makes use of [**Microsoft Graph**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/1.2.0#you-can-now-specify-scopes-and-app-permissions-for-graphserviceclient) or calling [**any other API**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/1.2.0#comfort-methods-for-idownstreamwebapi) super simple!

For more references, refer [about custom middleware in azure functions](https://hajekj.net/2020/12/12/microsoft-identity-web-and-azure-functions/) and [this](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-azure-function-with-azure-web-app-using-managed-service-identity/).

Comment: Ofc it has a concept for middleware.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware 

Filters are also not a good idea. They have been marked as "preview" for several years and have not been touched since.

Comment: Are you using .Net 6 Isolated version.  The isolated model gives you full control over the language worker startup configuration and provides useful features like dependency injection and middleware. If yes, please refer here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use this package [DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize/)

In your startup class initialize authentication:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddFunctionsAuthentication();
    .AddJwtBearer(options => 
     {
        //your JWT configuration here just like in ASPNET Core
     });

builder.Services.AddFunctionsAuthorization();
```

Then all you need to do is decorate your functions or functions class with `FunctionAuthorizeAttribute` and you can have the same granular control as in WebAPI:

```cs
[FunctionAuthorize(Policy = Permissions.Announcements.Edit)]
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyFunction(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "myfunction")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    var user = req.HttpContext.User;
    /* my code */
}
```

More information on this [blog post](https://blog.darkloop.com/post/functionauthorize-for-azure-functions-v3).